# form post method not working

Tags: php, html, post, methods

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Register</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <h3>Register Page</h3>
        <a href="index.php">Click here to go back</a></br>
        <form action="register.php" method="post">
            Enter Username: <input type="text" name="username" required="required"/></br>
            Enter Password: <input type="password" name="password" required="required"/></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

        echo "Username is :" . $username . "<br>";
        echo "Password is :" . $password;
    }
?>
```

When I execute the page with any random username and password it doesn't show me text and password inside the text box I wrote.

[image]

Comment: Try to var_dump($_POST) and see whats in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your php code with following:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

echo "Username is :" . $username . "<br>";
echo "Password is :" . $password;
}

?>
```

Comment: try to dump $_POST variable.

Comment: Okey i'v got it working. this code works.. thx. i accidentally put one ($) instead of ($$) on the if statement